# Python API to return values from NOAA

Tags: python-3.x

Background: I'm working with a Python project I was able to find online where the values from a NOAA weather station are returned via an API and displayed using the Print function, which I've had success in printing values to the Python editor, but my end goal is to populate these values into a MySQL database.  This is my first Python experience and have found that it's better for me to jump right into a project, rather than spending hours watching videos and reading.

Here is the code I'll be referencing:

```
from noaa_sdk import noaa
from datetime import date

tdate_ = date.today()

n = noaa.NOAA()
observations = n.get_observations('27858','US',start='2020-01-04',end='2020-01-04')
for observation in observations:
    print(observation)
```

Currently, there is a date parameter that only allows for a string to be entered.  You'll see that I have the datetime and tdate_ to bring in the relative date, however I've had issues inserting this into the string values below:

```
observations = n.get_observations('27858','US',start='2020-01-04',end='2020-01-04')
```

Ideally, this would reference today's date in all instances, which is the purpose of using tdate_.

I've looked online and found many similar situations, but I feel like there is always that caveat that doesn't match this scenario.  I really appreciate the help and look forward to learning more Python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was unclear.
I *think* you were asking:
How may I use a `tdate` string expression,
instead of the constant expression `'2020-01-04'` ?

First, the trailing underscore is weird, please don't do that.
We might assign to an identifier like `dir_`, `map_`, or `list_` because
we don't want to shadow (hide; mask; override) the builtin identifier.
Or here we might assign to `date_` to avoid shadowing the `datetime.date`
module you `import`ed.
Ok, enough said, we'll be working with this assignment:

```
tdate = date.today()
```

Now, your question seems to be prompted by the fact that this won't work:

```
... n.get_observations(..., start=tdate, ...)
```

since the `start` parameter is supposed to be a `str`, a string.
Fair enough.
That's easily remedied with a function call:

```
... n.get_observations(..., start=str(tdate), ...)
```

Equivalently, you could do what the `__str__` function is doing behind the scenes:

```
... n.get_observations(..., start=tdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), ...)
```

In either case you'll get a nice [ISO8601](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/iso_8601.png) date.
Do the same for the `end` parameter.

Comment: I feel like I tried this multiple times, but it didn't work.  I appreciate your help and other suggestions.